# Subject<any> catch the subscribe and unsubscribe methods

Tags: rxjs, rxjs5

I want to force an rxjs subject to have only one subscriber at a time.
and I want to count the number of subscriptions to enforce the condition

```
 import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';


/**
 * FormDialogActionModel
 */
export class FormDialogActionModel {
    public $customAction: Subject<CustomAction> = new Subject<CustomAction>();

    private positiveActionSubscribers: number = 0;
    private customActionSubscribers: number = 0;
    private $positiveAction: Subject<Object> = new Subject<Object>();    
    private internalToken = 'FORM-DIALOG-SERVICE-GET-POSITIVE-ACTION-WITHOUT-TRIGGERING-GET-RESTRICTIONS';

    /**
     * This get method was created to force the number of subscribers to 1
     */
    public get $$positiveAction(): Subject<Object>  {
        this.positiveActionSubscribers ++;
        if(this.positiveActionSubscribers > 1){
            throw new Error('Somebody already subscribed to a positive action. You cannot subscribe to it again until the subscribes unsubscribes');            
        }

        return this.$positiveAction;    
    }

    public unSubscribePositiveAction(){
        this.positiveActionSubscribers --;
    }

    public getPositiveAction(token){
        if(token != this.internalToken){
            throw new Error('The get mothod getPositiveAction was created only for form-dialog.service');
        }

        return this.$positiveAction;
    }
}

export interface CustomAction {
    data: Object;
    customActionIdentifier: string;
}
```

Is there a way to cache the subscribe event and increse the counter
 and unsubscribe to decrese it? I want the other clases to not know
 what's happening behind and this one to be forced to have only one
 subscriber on time

Comment: What is the reasoning behind having only one subscriber? Technically it wouldn't be transparent if you are throwing when a second subscription occurs

Comment: I have a global form dialog and I want to force the positive action to have one subscriber so somebody who will use it will not subscribe twice to the same event. I fixed the problem by extending Rxjs subject

Comment: The throw purpose is to be sure that a programmer uses the api correctly

Answer (score 0):

> A possible fix which looks pretty clean is to extend the Subject class and use this implementation instead

```
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
import { Observer } from 'rxjs/Observer';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { PartialObserver } from 'rxjs/Observer';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription';

export class RxSingleSubject<T> extends Subject<T>{

    constructor(destination?: Observer<T>, source?: Observable<T>) {
        super(destination, source);
    }

    subscribe(observerOrNext?: PartialObserver<T> | ((value: T) => void), error?: (error: any) => void, complete?: () => void): Subscription {
        if(this.observers.length == 1){
            throw new Error("RxjsSingleSubject does not support more then one subscriber.");            
        }

        return super.subscribe(observerOrNext, error, complete);
    }
}
```